# How to pass a boolean field from one activity to a class?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

How to pass, **at any time!**, a boolean field from one activity to a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own singleton class that both your Activity and other class can access at any time.  You have to be careful with it because it does add a layer of global variables (which people tend to not like), but it works.

```
public class MyBoolean{

   private static final MyBoolean instance = new MyBoolean();

   private boolean boolValue = false;

   private MyBoolean(){}

   public static MyBoolean getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   public boolean getValue(){
      return boolValue;
   }

   public void setValue(boolean newValue){
      boolValue = newValue;
   }
}
```

Call `MyBoolean.getInstance()` and you can use the methods inside which will be in sync with your whole program.

Answer (score 3):

Pass to Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NameOfActivity.class);
i.putExtra("my_boolean_key", myBooleanVariable);
startActivity(i)
```

Retrieve in Second Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean myBooleanVariable = bundle.getBoolean("my_boolean_key");
```